# Modal no aparece al usar filter: grayscale()

Tags: css, bootstrap, modal, filtro

Estoy realizando una página web en la cual muestro varios modales con bootstrap, todo funciona como debería, hasta el momento en que quiero aplicar un filtro de escala de grises a la página, en cuanto ocupo esta propiedad de CSS mis ventanas modal dejan de aparecer.

Cabe aclarar que como uso varias ventanas modal que muestran diferente información en PDF, los modales son llamados desde JavaScript para limpiar la información que contienen.

```html
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalPDF" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-notify modal-utxj" role="document">
            <!--Content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!--Header-->
                <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center;color: white;">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!--Body-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <object id="pdfdoc" width="100%" height="700px" type="application/pdf"></object>
                </div>
                <!--Footer-->
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <a id="bajar" type="button" class="btn btn-utxj">Descargar <i
                            class="far fa-file-pdf ml-1 text-white"></i></a>
                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-utxj" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar <i
                            class="fas fa-times ml-1"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Codigo JS

```javascript
//Mostrar Modales
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery(".showPDF").on("click", function () {
     var url = $(this).attr("rel");
     var txt = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
     jQuery("#myModalLabel").text(txt);
     jQuery("#pdfdoc").attr("data", url);
     jQuery("#bajar")
       .attr("download", txt + ".pdf")
       .attr("href", url);
   });
 });

 //Limpiar Modales
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery("#ModalPDF").on("hidden.bs.modal", function (e) {
     jQuery(this).removeData("bs.modal");
     jQuery(this).find(".modal-content").empty();

     jQuery(this)
       .find(".modal-content")
       .html(
         "<div class='modal-header' style='text-align: center;color: white;'>" +
           "<h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Modal title</h4>" +
           "<button type='button'class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>" +
           "<span aria-hidden='true' class='white-text'>&times;</span>" +
           "</button>" +
           "</div>" +
           "<div class='modal-body'>" +
           "<object id='pdfdoc' width='100%' height='700px' type='application/pdf'></object>" +
           "</div>" +
           "<div class='modal-footer justify-content-center'>" +
           "<a id='bajar' type='button' class='btn btn-utxj' >Descargar <i class='far fa-file-pdf ml-1 text-white'></i></a>" +
           "<a type='button' class='btn btn-outline-utxj' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar <i class='fas fa-times ml-1'></i></a>" +
           "</div>"
       );
   });
 });
```

Una vez que aplico la propiedad de `filter: grayscale()` a todo el body, los modales dejan de funcionar como lo hacían normalmente.

¿Porque pasa esto, y como puedo hacer que mis modales se muestren correctamente al usar filtros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mucho tiempo encontré la solución y de una manera muy sencilla, solamente se necesita agregar el siguiente código en la parte superior del archivo CSS y los modales funcionarán de manera correcta.

```
html {
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```